# Which characters are in which weight groups?

Tags: mario-kart-8

[According to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15852214#15852214):

> Characters are divided into weight groups. Each character in a weight group has identical stats.

What are the different weight groups, and which characters are in each?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *There are 30 playable characters in Mario Kart 8, consisting of 16 default characters and 14 unlockable characters. ...There are 3 weight classes dependent on the size of the kart the characters ride on (with the exception of Metal Mario and Pink Gold Peach): light, medium, and heavy.*

**Source:** [Mario Kart 8 - Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8#Characters)

## Light

#### Speed 2.25 Acceleration 3.25 Weight 2.25 Handling 4.75 Traction 4.5

- Baby Mario
- Baby Luigi
- Baby Peach
- Baby Daisy
- Baby Rosalina
- Lemmy

#### Speed 2.75 Acceleration 3 Weight 2.75 Handling 4.25 Traction 4.25

- Toad
- Koopa Troopa
- Shy Guy
- Larry
- Wendy
- Lakitu
- Toadette

## Medium

#### Speed 3.25 Acceleration 2.75 Weight 3.25 Handling 3.75 Traction 4

- Peach
- Daisy
- Yoshi

#### Speed 3.75 Acceleration 2.5 Weight 3.75 Handling 3.25 Traction 3.75

- Iggy
- Ludwig
- Mario
- Luigi

## Heavy

#### Speed 4.25 Acceleration 2.25 Weight 4.25 Handling 2.75 Traction 3.5

- Donkey Kong
- Waluigi
- Rosalina
- Roy

#### Speed 4.25 Acceleration 2 Weight 4.75 Handling 2.75 Traction 3.25

- Metal Mario
- Pink Gold Peach

#### Speed 4.75 Acceleration 2 Weight 4.75 Handling 2.25 Traction 3.25

- Morton
- Bowser
- Wario

A complete list of weight classes, differences within the weight classes, karts and items can be found on the [Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8#Drivers).

Comment: Your answer is misleading, because it highlights the three "primary" weight groups, but as you can see in your link each weight group is really further broken up into lesser weight groups. For example, Koopa Troopa and Lemmy both fall under "Light", but are actually in two separate weight groups which have their own unique stats. You should really modify your answer to show these sub divisions within the "primary" weight groups.

Comment: @Wipqozn Updated my answer to include the sub divisions. Better?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've swapped my downvote to an upvote.